# Providing Initial Data with Core Data in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, ios6

Here's what I need: To have a sqlite file populated with example entities that I made on the iPhone simulator, and then copy that file when the app initially runs for all my users.

What I've done:

1. I created a bunch of entries within the simulator.
2. I found the sqlite file attached to my app within the iPhone Simulator iOS folder on the MAC.
3. From the three files, .sqlite, .sqlite-shm, .sqlite-wal I simply copied the .sqlite file to my xCode project.
4. When I ran the app, the .sqlite file showed up empty!

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

What significance does the .sqlite-wal and .sqlite-shm have?

Why do they exist and why did not exist prior to iOS7?

Comment: Did you google what they are?

Answer (score 1):

- first steps R OK but then U have to load the database

U need smth like this:

```
- (void)copyPreparedDatabase{
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DATABASE.sqlite"];
    NSString *storePath = [storeURL path];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DATABASE" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if (defaultStorePath) {
        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:storePath error:&error];
        }
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:&error];

        NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:storePath error:&error]) {

        }
    }
}
```

And then U call it from - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator from 
AppDelelate.m

Advice: Do some custom switch like
    #define IMPORT_PREPARED_DATABASE

do it like this:
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath] && !IMPORT_PREPARED_DATABASE) { //&& 1==2
        [self copyPreparedDatabase];
    }

so U can control when to build new prepared database or when to use existing one....

Note:
When U build new prepared database sto simulator, copy database and paste it over the old one...

Comment: You should try to write your answers correctly, without "R OK" or "smth". Be aware that not everybody understands that kind of abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated) can be a big help.

You made almost everything, but you are missing an important step. You need to copy the sqlite to your xcode project then you need to check in your `persistentStoreCoordinator` if the sqlite file exists in your Documents area. If not, you need to copy it. Jump to "Doctor, you’re needed in Xcode" section in that tutorial :).